# Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Tags: aws-codebuild

I am trying to login to ECR from aws codebuild. Buit is says Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device. I have attached **AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess** and **AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryPowerUser** policy with the service role of codebuild. Still it says

"An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device"

I am trying to implement CI/CD using AWS pipeline. On codebuild am trying to build docker image and push it to ECR.

Comment: The problem is solved. On codebuild buildspec.yaml file I have added some dummy env AWS_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY these variables were the source of the problem. When I removed this variable the problem is solved.